# How to create a list from api reponse and remove duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython

I want to make a list from api json response as shown for each ticket in jira and remove any duplicates

I can get the values for each ticket but not able to make it as list and remove duplicates from it to process

Here is the api json response for each ticket

```
response = {
    "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
    "id": "1831845",
    "self": "https://jira.com/login/rest/api/latest/issue/1845",
    "key": "pc-1002",
    "fields": {
                 "customfield_1925": {
                    "self": "https://jira.com/login/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/1056",
                    "value": "windows",
                    "id": "101056"
                }
```

so i have script like this:

```
import requests, json

tick = """jira: pc-1002,pc-1003,pc-1005
env"""
ticks = tick.replace(' ','').split(':')[1].split('\n')[0].split(',')
print(ticks)

for i in ticks:
    url = "https://jira.com/login/rest/api/latest/issue/" + str(i)
    print(url)

    response = requests.request("GET", url, verify=False)
    response = json.loads(response.text)
    resp = response['fields']['customfield_1925']['value']   
    print(resp)
```

so it prints all the values like below :
output:

windows1
windows2
windows1

I want the output values to be unique and as it may end up having duplicates.

I wanted output as below

['windows1', 'windows2']

Comment: [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is possibly a good match. There is even an example in the docs for getting unique keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add each response to a list of responses, and use Python's convenient "in" operator to check if each response is already in the list. Something along the lines of:

```
    allResponses = []
    for i in ticks:
        url = "https://jira.com/login/rest/api/latest/issue/" + str(i)
        print(url)

        response = requests.request("GET", url, verify=False)
        response = json.loads(response.text)
        resp = response['fields']['customfield_1925']['value']
        if resp not in allResponses:   
            print(resp)
            allResponses.append(resp)
```

Comment: This works great, but the resp value has unicode character like [u'test', u'test2'], how do remove those u' ?

Comment: If it's always just one 'u' at the beginning, you can trim out the first character by using Python string slicing. I think that changing "resp = response['fields']['customfield_1925']['value']" to "resp = response['fields']['customfield_1925']['value'][1:] should do it.

Comment: it is slicing first letter like [u'test', u'test2'] to [u'est', u'est2']

Comment: its basically having resp value as [u'test', u'test2 - tests2 - test3'], so it it adding it as [u'test', u'test2 \u2013 tests2 \u2013 test3'] , \u2013 is causing issue.

Comment: String managing your unique entries is another problem, sorry I couldn't do that one off the top of my head - could you mark my answer as solving your original problem for this post?